# Set dropdown list based on the value in URL

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dotnetnuke

i have a page which is using another navigation bar.ascx for a country dropdown. Now when i select a countryfrom that dropdown, correspoding page opens in a new tab. and that dropdown is loaded again. I want the dropdown to show the current country selected. the country name is in the URL.

I just have a ascx file and no cs file for this. So how can it be done with a JS so that i can keep the js on the nav bar page itself. and it just checks the country name from the url and shows that value as selected in the dropdown of the new page.

```
<select onchange="open(this.value,'','');">
   <option>Select Region</option>
   <option value="/africa">Africa</option>
   <option value="/Australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="/Europe">Europe</option>
   <option value="/Latin-America">Latin America</option>
   <option value="/Middle-east">Middle East</option>
   <option value="/North-America">North America</option>
   <option value="/South-Asia">South Asia</option>
   <option value="/South-East-Asia">South East Asia</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Please post your JS - we don't know what `open` does.

Comment: What has DotNetNuke to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method -

```
onchange="window.open(this.value, '_blank').focus()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get url of the page using javascript

on page load event of javascript/jquery you can get url and manipulate that value

```
window.location.href
```

This will give you the URL of the page now you can manipulate value of url according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready() fetch your country name from the url.you can get the current url as `window.location.href` after that set the country name as selected in the Drop Down 
Example code: -

```
$document.ready(function(){
  var countryname = windows.location.href;
  $(select).val(countryname);
 }
);
```

Get Your country name from the url using `split()` method.